# CompositeFilter of CompositeFilter on Google Data Store using Java Client

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, vert.x

I am trying to filter a query using `CompositeFilter.and()` consisting two `CompositeFilter.and()`s.

```
Query<Entity>query = queryBuilder.setKind("ExampleKind")
      .setFilter(CompositeFilter.and(
          CompositeFilter.and(
              PropertyFilter.eq("PropertyA", new Long("1")), 
              PropertyFilter.ge("PropertyB", "ValueB")),
          CompositeFilter.and(
              PropertyFilter.eq("PropertyC", "ValueC"), 
              PropertyFilter.ge("PropertyD", new Long("4"))
          ))
          .setLimit(pageSize)
          .build();
```

Sadly, I seem not to be able to walk my results or receive any results.

Here are my indices from the index.yaml file:

```
- kind: ExampleKind
  properties:
  - name: PropertyA
    direction: asc
  - name: PropertyB
    direction: asc

- kind: ExampleKind
  properties:
  - name: PropertyC
    direction: asc
  - name: PropertyD
    direction: asc
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

A query can only have inequality on a single property.  It's documented in a clear way in the [Go documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/query-restrictions#inequality_filters_are_limited_to_at_most_one_property).  To do the query you want you'll need to do two queries and merge the results yourself.